# Assign cctype function to std::function, gcc compile error

Tags: c++

Hi I hope you like this question. I’m talking about the functions `iscntrl`, `isprint`, etcetera in the include file `cctype`. All these functions take an `int` and return an `int`.

The following code example did run fine in Wandbox with compiler set to clang. But on my mingw-w64, gcc8.1 it did produce compile errors. I tried both C++14 and C++17.

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
//#include <ctype.h>

namespace abc
{
  int two_times( int a )
  {
    printf( "two_times being called\n" );
    return 2*a;
  }

  int three_times( int a )
  {
    printf( "three_times being called\n" );
    return 3*a;
  }
}

int main()
{
  typedef std::tuple< std::string, std::function<int(int)> > item_t;
  std::array< item_t, 3 > array{
    std::make_tuple( "three_times", abc::three_times ),
    std::make_tuple( "two_times", abc::two_times ),
    std::make_tuple( "iscntrl", std::iscntrl ) };

  int i = 2;

  for( const item_t& item : array )
  {
    printf( "operation: %s\n", std::get<0>(item).c_str() );
    int val = std::get<1>(item)( i );
    printf( "val: %d\n", val );
    putchar( '\n' );
  }

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see I put all of the relevant stuff that my loop would need into an array. Including the function objects that are assigned to the cctype functions.

The functions two_times and three_times are there to show the rest of my design is fine. If I just use these functions it works. But in my eyes `std::iscntrl` is just another function that have an `int` as argument and returns an `int`. But apparently not, because it produces the following compile error:

```
error: too many arguments to function 'constexpr std::tuple<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Elements>::__type ...> std::make_tuple(_Elements&& ...) [with _Elements = {}]'
     std::make_tuple( "iscntrl", std::iscntrl ) };
```

Oh yeah, if you replace the include file with `#include <ctype.h>` and remove the `std::` namespace label in front of `iscntrl` it suddenly works as well. But that is not good practice. But maybe it tells you something.

Making it even simpler, neither gets it working:

```cpp
std::function<int(int)> f;
f = abc::two_times;
printf( “result: %d\n“, f( 4 ) ); // so far fine
f = std::iscntrl;
```

Then at the last line:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::function<int(int)>' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>')
   f = std::iscntrl;
```

Did I something wrong? What would be a simple solution to get it to compile with gcc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few functions in the standard library (since C++20) are so-called [*addressable functions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). All others may only be called with appropriate arguments, not have their address taken.

Even before that, the standard didn't guarantee absence of overloads, which had nearly the same effect.

In your case, there is

- [`int iscntrl( int ch );` in `<cctype>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/iscntrl) and
- [`template< class charT >
  bool iscntrl( charT ch, const locale& loc );` in `<locale>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/iscntrl).

Even if you only included the first header directly, all standard headers may include any of the others aside from the C and adopted ones, so they are potentially both available.

As you pass to a template-argument, the compiler cannot disambiguate which of the overloads you meant.

What you should do is pass a lambda forwarding as needed. As a bonus, you can use that to force the argument into the proper range for `unsigned char`, avoiding undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works fine with the lambda. Good to know most library functions are non-addressable from C++20.

Answer (score 2):

`std::iscntrl` is referred to as an `<unresolved overloaded function type>` in the error because in C++ this function is indeed overloaded. There is a `int iscntrl( int )` overload from the `<cctype>` header and a `bool iscntrl( charT ch, const locale& loc )` overload from `<locale>`. The compiler doesn't know which function to choose when you pass it like that.

To resolve this and still use the C++ version you must pass a function that calls `iscntrl` from within:

```c++
std::make_tuple( "iscntrl", [](int c) { return std::iscntrl(c); } );
```

Comment: And probably OP could only reproduce it on GCC because `<locale>` ended up being included by some other standard header in libstdc++, but not in libc++. Huh.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, I put #include <locale> in Wandbox and try to compile with clang. Now clang also produce compile errors.